# Having trouble while accessing the elements from arraylist when i key in user input

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am facing a problem which is when i try to check the user input if it matches with the elements in my arraylist, it will not show the respective elements.
I did not get the output i want, as i keep getting the false statement(in if-else). Hope to seek for any kinds of advice (Still a beginner into Java Programming).Thanks!

//Code for accessing,comparing arraylist elements with user input from text file

```
       String line1;
       BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(newFileReader("Connection.txt"));
        while((line1 = br.readLine())!= null)
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line1, "____");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {   
                String first = st.nextToken();
                String last = st.nextToken();
                Connection a = new Connection(first, last);
                ConnectArray.add(a);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Enter:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();   
        System.out.println("The connections are:\n");

        for(int x= 0; x<ConnectArray.size(); x++)
        {
            if(input.equals(ConnectArray.get(x).getConnection1()))
            {
                System.out.println(ConnectArray.get(x).getConnection2());
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The connections you have inputted is wrong! Please try again");
                break;
            }
```

}

Comment: What is Connection refers.?

Comment: It is my the other java file to implement and setter and getter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever your input is, you only compare it with the first line in the file, since there is a `break` statement in the `if` block *and* in the `else` block.

You shouldn't stop looping in the `else` block: other lines might contain the input. And if several lines are supposed to match with the input as your comment implies, you shouldn't have a `break` in the `if` block either: other lines might also match with the input.

That said, there could also be other bugs in the Connection class. But you didn't show it. You also didn't tell what your file contains, and what your input is, so it's hard to provide more help.

Comment: ok i edit the code again. i have added the other class. thanks

Comment: Except for the problems stated in my answer, your code works fine. So you must be reading another file than the one you think. Use a debugger. Or at least print everything you read from the file. Also, please respect the Java naming conventions: variables start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: i don't think im reading another file because i can print out the .txt file when running the program.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: I took your code, added the missing white space between `new` and `FileReader`, added the missing ConnectArray list declaration, put all thet code in a main method, copied and pasted the content of the file you posted into a Connection.txt file, and then executed the code, and it worked as expected. Have you fixed the bugs I showed in my answer? Why don't you post the complete code your're trying to execute, including the print debug statements you added, and tell us what the output is?

Comment: Ok. i solved my problems already. It's working fine now! Thanks a lot for the help :D